# Elasticsearch: Restore snapshot with different shards number

Tags: elasticsearch, backup, sharding, snapshot

I have created an [Elasticsearch snapshot](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_restoring_from_a_snapshot.html) and want to restore it with a different number of shards: My old cluster uses 5 shards for every index, I want to reduce it to 2 shards.

Is this somehow possible to do this with the Elasticsearch snapshot API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with Elasticsearch snapshot API.
Internally snapshot is taken per shard and it is restored also in the same manner.

-- Edit ---

We have [shrink API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-shrink-index.html) now , which can reduce number shard but only to a devisiable number.

Comment: Too bad. As all information exists, it shouldn't be too difficult to implement a tool for this.

Comment: Re indexing is the only way. The issue is that the reverse index is also a part of index , not just the data. This data needs to be merged/split for increasing or decreasing the shard. Changing the routing function will also bring in substantial amount of work too.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about replica (Since i have similar problem before):

```
POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
{
  "indices": "index_1",
  "index_settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "ignore_index_settings": [
    "index.refresh_interval"
  ]
}
```

[The document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_changing_index_settings_during_restore) have this line of code that can change your number of replicas during the restore porcess.

However, number of shards will not able to change.

Is there any reason you want to change shards? (if you are not talking about replicas)

**Edit One:**
To change shards, like @Vineeth Mohan said, re-indexing is only way as far as I know.

Comment: Example: Our data have `pri: 3; rep: 1` and when I use this to restore data to a single node testing cluster, I can reduce this to `pri: 3; rep: 0`. So yea, this will not change shards but only replica.

Answer (score 1):

Restore to a dummy index with the wrong number of shards.

Then reindex to a new index with the correct number of shards.